# Is there a way to make SQL standard compliant queries using Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sql

I just wanted to know if there is an SQL standard compliance validator out there for Visual Studio 2019 Professional (something that could be set to **strict**: only absolutely compliant syntax would be accepted). It would be nice if it had support for native languages too, but I'm used to that kind of stuff being **CLR-only** (I don't really know why probably because of linking... I may be so absolutely wrong, though... I actually have no idea and took a guess).

Something important would be that it needs to be standard compliant, not only SQL-server compliant. What is not in the standard is an error.

The goal is to make SQL code that is completely independent of the DBMS. Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: "The goal is to make SQL code that is completely independent of the DBMS" this is hardly ever reachable. Different DBMSes can behave differently executing the same query.

Comment: Start with using only Core SQL functionality, listed inhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance. You can also use https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ to verify the syntax. Common problems are different date/time and string functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The goal is to make SQL code that is completely independent of the DBMS.

Impossible goal, unless you are going to forsake writing SQL at all.  It is perhaps sad, but different databases differ on very fundamental things, picking and choosing the parts of the standard they want.  Happily, the *major* things like `SELECT`, `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` are common but the details are not.

You can think of them of them like dialects of a spoken language over time and region.  I'm most familiar with English, but it is true that all languages evolve and change.  I can *read* Shakespearean English, but I am not going to *write* English like that.  It would be grammatically incorrect in some cases, use unknown words, and alternative meanings of common words.

Here are just some examples of some features that differ widely among databases:

1. Intervals.  Adding an interval to a date using the standard syntax is `interval + '1 day'`.  This varies significantly across databases.
2. Some databases do not support `FULL JOIN`.
3. Some databases do not support recursive CTEs.  Some use the `recursive` keyword; some do not.
4. Some databases do not support the `VALUES()` constructor in the `FROM` clause.
5. Some databases allow the `FROM` clause to be optional.
6. The standard has nifty functionality such as `FILTER` and aggregation by functionally dependent ids.that few databases support
7. Limitations on data types vary significantly -- what is the longer string, for instance.
8. The standard uses `FETCH` to limit results, which some databases do not support.
9. Parsing strings into dates and formatting dates into strings is totally database-dependent.
10. Extracting date/time components uses `extract()` in the standard, but few databases actually support that functionality.

These are just a few of the differences off the top of my head -- in no way meant to be complete or even the most important.  I just want to point out that what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: Such a shame that an all-important standard like SQL should be so mistreated to the point where it's actually impossible to write 100% compliant code that would run in all databases. Even if a DBMS has a better way of doing something it should also implement the standard and recommend clients should use their dialect instead if they want better performance or whatever is the trade-off they offer.